# Set default featured image for terms of a custom taxonomy

Tags: theme-development, custom-taxonomy

I want to set a default featured image for terms of a custom taxonomy.

I found this code but it is only good for categories and not for other terms:

```
<?php if (  (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) && (has_post_thumbnail())) : ?>

<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?>

<?php else :?>

<img src="whatever/directory/<?php $category = get_the_category(); echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?>.jpg" /> 

<?php endif;?>
```

How can I make this code also work for a custom taxonomy?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using  `get_the_category()` use [**get_terms()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
so something like this:

```
<img src="whatever/directory/<?php $terms = get_terms('TAXONOMY_NAME'); echo $terms[0]->term_name; ?>.jpg" />
```